# Prove that $f(z)=g(z)$ on $D$ considering Taylor expansions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-problem

Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable on the strip
$D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: -2 < \operatorname{Im}z <2$. Suppose that $ f(z) =g(z)$ for all $z$ such that $|z|<0.01$. By considering Taylor expansions first about $0$, then $1$, and so on by induction, prove that $f(z)=g(z)$ on $D$.

Is it safe simply to state the Identity Theorem? If not, I am lost and need some assistance

Identity Theorem:  If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable in a domain $D$ and $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z \in S \subseteq D$ where $S$ has a limit point in $D$, then $f=g$ throughout $D$.

Comment: It sounds like this is an exercise whose intent is for you to prove the result specifically using Taylor expansions, as practice for later understanding the proof of the identity theorem. In general, when a homework problem says "by using [specific method]", I would definitely use that specific method.

Comment: in this case, i am kind of lost

Comment: Where are you encountering this problem? Book? Lecture? Have you covered the identity principle? If so, that's a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $f=g$ for $|z| <0.01$ implies that the power series expansions of $f$ and $g$ in the disk $D(0,2)$ have the same coefficients: the coefficients are simply $\frac  {f^{(n)} (0)} {n!}$ and  $\frac  {g^{(n)} (0)} {n!}$. This proves that $f=g$ in $D(0,2)$. Now we already know that $f=g$ is some disk around $1$ so we can repeat the argument (using power series around the point $1$) to conlude that $f=g$ in $D(1,2)$, and so on. Thus, $f=g$ in $D(n,2)$ for each $n$ and hence $f=g$ on the part of the domain where $\Re z \geq 0$. Similar argument holds for the part $\Re z \leq 0$.

Comment: how do we know they have the same coefficients in D(0,2)?

Comment: $f=g$ in some open disk around $0$ implies that $f'(z)=g'(z),f''(z)=g''(z)$ etc in that disk Hence, all the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ at $0$ are the same and these are the coefficients in the power series expansion. @pop